# Create NSArray with row content (MySQL)

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, objective-c, nsarray

I want to create a NSArray witch contains the content of a MySQL table row

I use a php script to get the data

```
$response = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM iPhoneTests');


while ($datas = $response->fetch())
{
?>
    <array>
    <integer><?php echo $datas['Temperature']; ?></integer>
    </array>


<?php
}
```

and to test Iuse this code in my app

```
    NSURL *getTemperature = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myURL..."];  
    NSError* error;
    temperature = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:getTemperature ];
    NSLog(@"%@",temperature);
```

When I test in my web broswer I get all my datas but in my app, with the NSlog I only get the first value.

I on this problem since a few time, but I can't succeed 
If someone see my mistake please tell me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating an array for each row (which by the way is invalid, because those arrays would have to be nested into an array, too).

Do it in this way:

```
$response = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM iPhoneTests');
?><array><?
while ($datas = $response->fetch())
{
?>
    <integer><?php echo $datas['Temperature']; ?></integer>
<?
}
?></array>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can communicate in many ways with server. And I would suggest that communication data should only be in String format, one way is using JSON, you can get JSON parser from here https://github.com/schwa/TouchJSON , this is explained as below:

1. Starting Communication

   [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
   [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]] delegate:self startImmediately:YES] autorelease];
   //urlStr is NSString ref
2. Start receiving data

   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:
     (NSURLResponse *)response{
     [receivedData setLength:0];
     }
     //receivedData is NSMutableData ref
3. Get data in chunks

   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
     [receivedData appendData:data];
     }
4. After getting complete data

   - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

     // json data retrival complete    (received data is NSMutableData)
     if(receivedData == nil || [receivedData length] == 0){
       //handle error in getting response, may be no network
         [self showAlertViewWithTitle:@"No network" andMessage:@"Could not open the
         page, because internet connection was not found." andTag:0];
         return;
     }

     NSString *responseBody = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData
       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
     ////NSLog(responseBody);
     NSError *jsonParsingError = [[[NSError alloc] init] autorelease];
     NSDictionary * jsonData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithJSONData:
                                  [responseBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                      error:&jsonParsingError];

     NSDictionary *serverError = [jsonData objectForKey:@"error"]==[NSNull null]?
                                    nil:[jsonData objectForKey:@"error"];

     if(serverError==nil || [serverError count]==0){
         // no error found else
         NSDictionary *response = [jsonData objectForKey:@"response"]==[NSNull null]?
                                    nil:[jsonData objectForKey:@"response"];
         NSArray *array = [response objectForKey:@"array"]==[NSNull null]?nil:
                               [response objectForKey:@"array"];
     // I have left the code incomplete, its just for understanding
5. Check for null values
   Never forget to check null values from JSON data as follows:

   NSString *dataValue =  [[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"key"]==[NSNull null]?
                            @"0":[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"key"] intValue];

Please let me know if you require further explanation..

Comment: I think you've missed the point a little. ciwol is already passing the data as a string, and whilst he could do the fetch in a better manner in terms of error handling, he's clearly already successfully connecting to his server.

Comment: Thats fine, my point was to show him more better way to get data from server, this will help him to manage more proper error handling if some failure happens on server or client is not able to read the data array properly due to mismatch in format...

Comment: thank you anyway for your answer it's not gonna be useless, I'll see that